# Calculating time differences in a one to many dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I recently downloaded my League of Legends Data.  I have the following DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'DateTime': {
    0: 156102273400,
    1: 156101627200,
    2: 156092208200,
    3: 1559897767000,
    4: 1559890046000,
    5: 1559889968000},
                      'EventType': {
    0: 'LOGOUT_USER',
    1: 'LOGIN',
    2: 'LOGOUT_USER',
    3: 'LOGIN',
    4: 'LOGIN',
    5: 'LOGIN'}})
```

I get the following df:

```py
>>>df
Index    DateTime          EventType
0        156102273400      LOGOUT_USER
1        156101627200      LOGIN
2        156092208200      LOGOUT_USER
3        1559897767000     LOGIN
4        1559890046000     LOGIN
5        1559889968000     LOGIN
```

I want to map one single `LOGOUT_USER` to the minimum `LOGIN` before the next `LOGOUT_USER` is encountered.  From there I should be able to calculate the total time played.

---

Ideal output would look as follows:

```py
>>>fixed_df
Index    DateTime          EventType
0        156102273400      LOGOUT_USER
1        156101627200      LOGIN
2        156092208200      LOGOUT_USER
3        1559889968000     LOGIN
```

Comment: Is datetime always sorted ascending like in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `groupby` and `idxmin`.

```
grouper = df['EventType'].ne(df['EventType'].shift()).cumsum()
df.loc[df.groupby(grouper)['DateTime'].idxmin()]  

        DateTime    EventType
0   156102273400  LOGOUT_USER
1   156101627200        LOGIN
2   156092208200  LOGOUT_USER
5  1559889968000        LOGIN
```

Comment: This is a good solution.  I want to confirm my understanding.  The first line of code that assigns `grouper` does the following: Creates a group where the pd.Series `EventType` is not equal to the event type directly below it. This would group `LOGOUT_USER` to many `LOGIN` entries directly below. The second line sums all groups column `DateTime`, however since we are using .idxmin(), this will only select the minimum `DateTime` for a particular group.  Is this logic correct?

Comment: @VictorNogueira All consecutive LOGOUT_USER and LOGIN user rows will be grouped separately. Your understanding for what `idxmin` does is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
df.groupby(df.eventType.eq('LOGOUT_USER').cumsum()).agg(['first','last'])\
    .stack(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[634]: 
        dateTime    eventType
0   156102273400  LOGOUT_USER
1   156101627200        LOGIN
2   156092208200  LOGOUT_USER
3  1559889968000        LOGIN
```

Comment: Seems like a straight idxmin problem :)

Comment: This solution also works, however I believe that cs95's solution may be (subjectively) more readable

Answer (score 0):

Without groupby, you can combine your logic:

```
# logouts
log_out = df.eventType.eq('LOGOUT_USER')

# before login
next_log_in = df.eventType.shift(-1).eq('LOGIN')

# logout followed by login    
markers = log_out & next_log_in

# those logouts and logins after
df[markers | markers.shift()]
```

Output:

```
        dateTime    eventType
0   156102273400  LOGOUT_USER
1   156101627200        LOGIN
2   156092208200  LOGOUT_USER
3  1559897767000        LOGIN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up an extra group label `g` (plus `EventType`) and then drop_duplicates without running `groupby`:

```
df.assign(g=df['EventType'].eq('LOGOUT_USER').cumsum()) \
  .drop_duplicates(['g','EventType'], keep='last') \
  .drop('g', axis=1)

#        DateTime    EventType
#0   156102273400  LOGOUT_USER
#1   156101627200        LOGIN
#2   156092208200  LOGOUT_USER
#5  1559889968000        LOGIN
```